# Amazon EBS EC2 instance IP changed on restart

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, virtual-machine, amazon-ebs

I am running an EBS backed Amazon EC2 Linux instance. For some maintenance purposes I shutdown the machine and started it again. However, my machine IP has changed now. This affects my services since the server won't be reachable now.

Can this be repaired. Can I assign the same IP to the machine again?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S - The maintenance was that I shut down the machine so I could create and AMI out of it to share it with another user.

Comment: This is why Amazon encourages its users to use Elastic IPs, because it is unable to guarantee you that instances keep their own IP address trough their whole lifetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give the EC2 box an Elastic IP, otherwise when you restart the machine it'll have a new IP.  You can reuse this IP on different EC2 boxes but it will mean you have a constant IP to reference so say you lose your EC2 box and have to restore again from a EBS, it will still have the allocated static IP.

Comment: Should clarify this. You will not loose an IP on restart. You will if you stop, then start the instance again later. Elastic IP addresses will also become disassociated in that scenario, but its trivial to re-associate it.

Comment: Ah yeah, but you still have the address allocated to your account, either way I'm pretty sure it'd solve OP's issues.  Elastic IP's are dirt cheap too.

Comment: @datasage - well i didn't know about this and didn't have an elastic IP. Will keep it in mind for the future. i've lost that IP now. thanks :-)